# Is there a way to precompile kendo ui templates

Tags: javascript, templates, kendo-ui

I am interested in a mechanism to process my kendo ui templates and lets say precompile them with something like a grunt tasks. In that way I can just use them without the overhead of compiling on the browser.

Any ideas?